# multidownload using java servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I want to download multiple files in single zip file using java servlet. I successfully downloaded the zip file containing multiple files (in my web page). but the problem is that files are also downloaded in my server(for ex in my jboss bin folder).

**Code:**

```
public void createZipFile(String fileNames,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) {

        try {
            ZipOutputStream outStream1 = null;
            ServletOutputStream outStream=null;
            FileInputStream inStream =null;
            FileOutputStream fos=null;
            InputStream inputStream =null;
            int bytesRead = 0;


            String zipFileName = "zipFileName.zip";
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+zipFileName+"\"");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "private");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, max-age=0");
            response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            response.setContentType("application/zip");


            //fileNames contains multiple file name.so i want to split and get each file

            String[] fileName = fileNames.split(",");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            outStream1 = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
            for(int i = 0; i < fileName.length; i++) {
                String filePath=audioFile.getAllFiles(fileName[i], Integer.parseInt(userId));
                inputStream = new URL("************************server File location***************************").openStream();
                String fileNaming = fileName[i];
                String[] tempFile = fileNaming.split("\\.");
                String tempFileExt=tempFile[1];
                String temporaryFile=tempFile[0]+"."+tempFileExt;



                fos = new FileOutputStream(temporaryFile);//here is the problem(temporary file created in my server -bin folder.but i dont want this to create)


                int length = -1;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                inStream = new FileInputStream(fileName[i]);
                outStream1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName[i]));
                fos.close();
                inputStream.close();
                while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outStream1.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream1.closeEntry();

            outStream1.close();
            int bytesRead1 = 0;
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream inStream1 =new FileInputStream(zipFileName);
            while ((bytesRead1 = inStream1.read(buff)) != -1)
            {
                bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead1);
            }

            byte[] videoBytes = bao.toByteArray();
            response.setContentLength(videoBytes.length);
            outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(videoBytes);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            bao.close();
            response.flushBuffer();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, you're copying the files twice. Once, to the file system via `inputStream` and `fos`, and the second time to the ZipFile, via `inStream` and `outStream1`.

Seems like you can simply remove all of the code related to `inputStream` and `fos`, and you won't create the files on your filesystem.